# composer error while updating ".git directory is missing"

Tags: git, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php

When I Updating zf-commons/zfc-admin using composer, it gives an RuntimeException error saying that

> [RuntimeException]
>     The .git directory is missing from /var/www/site2.com/vendor/zf-commons/zfc
>     -admin, see http://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information

Since this error i cannot update any other modules in framework.

Answer (score 63):

When ever I have "issues" with composer the first thing I do is delete the vendor folder and do a "composer update"

You could also try to delete just that one component "vendor/zf-commons"

Comment: deleting the vendor folder fixed the issue

Comment: deleting the specific vendor's folder had worked for me

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to remove the install folder of that component before making the composer update

```
rm -rf  /var/www/site2.com/vendor/zf-commons/zfc
composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

delete zf-commons/zfc-admin then execute composer update.
usually you are not adviced to commit  zf-commons/zfc-admin to your repository