# The .git directory is missing from /var/www vendor/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions, see http://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

When i ran 
    php composer.phar update beberlei/DoctrineExtensions 
   i got above error

i read  http://getcomposer.org/commit-deps

but can't understand it proper

and in solution i found

[composer error while updating ".git directory is missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012061/composer-error-while-updating-git-directory-is-missing)

but deleting vender directory is not a good idea (i suppose) Does any one have any other good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting vendor, you can delete the beberlei/DoctrineExtensions directory, it will be faster.

There is no risk at deleting the entire directory, because you can recreate it with a `composer update` (the only drawback is that it takes time).