# How upgrade propel 1.6 to 1.7?

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I have a project with Symfony 2.6.4 and Propel 1.6.6-dev. I want upgrade propel to 1.7, How I do? In the official documentation I don't see how upgrade it.

I am using Composer.

I am getting this error when I run `composer update`:

> The .git directory is missing from /vendor/pkpass/pkpass, see getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information

Comment: How are you pulling in Propel - are you using Composer? I don't recall their being any backwards-incompatible changes from 1.6 to 1.7, have you checked the changelist?

Comment: Yes, I use Composer. Yes, I checked the changes

Comment: OK, so please edit in your new `composer.json` into your question, indicating what change you made. Then if you can run `composer update`, try your app and let us know what _specific_ problems you are running into?

Comment: The .git directory is missing from /vendor/pkpass/pkpass, see http://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information

Comment: Possible duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012061/composer-error-while-updating-git-directory-is-missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git clone git://github.com/propelorm/Propel lib/propel